# How to Learn Python on an Android Tablet

Tags: android, python, tablet

My brother got excited about coding and would like to learn it. I recommended him Python as the first language. It will be ideal if he can experiment, make first programs on his andoid tablet.

Online solutions like [Pythonanywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com/) are not usable in the default browser: When pressing a key in python console, the screen jumps to the top of page.

We looked for native apps and found only QPython which isn't very beginner friendly: it can't evaluate `print` statements, program fails when there is traceback (many times for a beginner who forgets about a ':' after for, if, and while)

How to learn python on an android tablet? What app or which website to use?

Comment: You want to do the development on the tablet, not just deploy apps onto the tablet after devloping them on a PC/Mac? While I can see the advantage of being able to develop on a relatively small device that can be carried around practically everywhere, I'd recommend against this. Especially for someone just starting out. Software development tools using a PC/Mac as a host tend to be much more mature and easy to set up and use.

Comment: I don't want brother to do the development on the tablet but let him play with the language. Something like codeacademy which doesn't work in the browser on the tablet.

Answer (score 4):

check this out: https://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/ 
With this he should be able to run actual python code on his device. 
Give him an ebook to read and he can try the examples on his tablet :)